# Performance of query with OR condition between join tables

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, query-optimization

There are two tables, tparent and tchild, which are created using script #1.
It's need to query all the information from the two tables where uname is equal to 'sky'.
The following query statement #2 is fast when there are only a few of records.
But it will become very slowly when inserting a huge number of records using the following script #3.
I think it's caused by the OR condition between tables and the index will be unusefull for querying. 
So I got a fast solution that changing the statement to three sub ones and union result, like #4.
I want to konw is there a better solution? what's it?

Thanks!

**# 1**

```
drop table tparent;
drop table tchild;
create table tparent(typeid int,sno number,uname varchar2(50) );
create table tchild(typeid int,sno number,seqno int,uname varchar2(50));
create unique index uidx_tparent_typeidsno on tparent(typeid,sno);
create unique index uidx_tchild_typeidsnoseqno on tchild(typeid,sno,seqno);
create index idx_tparent_name on tparent(uname);
create index idx_tchild_name on tchild(uname);

insert into tparent values (1,10,'lily');
insert into tparent values (1,11,'eric');
insert into tparent values (2,10,'tom');
insert into tparent values (2,11,'eric');
insert into tparent values (3,10,'sky');

insert into tchild values (1,10,1,'sam');
insert into tchild values (1,10,2,'sky');
insert into tchild values (1,11,1,'eric');
insert into tchild values (1,11,2,'john');
insert into tchild values (2,10,1,'sky');
insert into tchild values (2,11,1,'eric');
insert into tchild values (3,10,1,'tony');
```

**# 2**

```
select p.typeid,p.sno,p.uname,c1.uname as uname1,c2.uname as uname2 from tparent p
  left join tchild c1 on c1.typeid=p.typeid and c1.sno = p.sno and c1.seqno=1
  left join tchild c2 on c2.typeid=p.typeid and c2.sno = p.sno and c2.seqno=2
where (p.uname='sky' or c1.uname='sky' or c2.uname='sky');
```

**# 3**

```
BEGIN
    FOR x IN 1..10
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            FOR y IN 10000..100000
            LOOP
                BEGIN
                    insert into tparent values (x,y,'name'|| y);
                    insert into tchild values (x,y,1,'name'|| y);
                    insert into tchild values (x,y,2,'name'|| y);
                END;
            END LOOP;
            COMMIT;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

**#4**

```
select typeid,sno,max(uname),max(uname1),max(uname2) from (

select p.typeid,p.sno,p.uname,c1.uname as uname1,c2.uname as uname2 from tparent p
  left join tchild c1 on c1.typeid=p.typeid and c1.sno = p.sno and c1.seqno=1
  left join tchild c2 on c2.typeid=p.typeid and c2.sno = p.sno and c2.seqno=2
where (p.uname='sky' )
union 
select p.typeid,p.sno,p.uname,c1.uname as uname1,c2.uname as uname2 from tparent p
  left join tchild c1 on c1.typeid=p.typeid and c1.sno = p.sno and c1.seqno=1
  left join tchild c2 on c2.typeid=p.typeid and c2.sno = p.sno and c2.seqno=2
where ( c1.uname='sky' )
union

select p.typeid,p.sno,p.uname,c1.uname as uname1,c2.uname as uname2 from tparent p
  left join tchild c1 on c1.typeid=p.typeid and c1.sno = p.sno and c1.seqno=1
  left join tchild c2 on c2.typeid=p.typeid and c2.sno = p.sno and c2.seqno=2
where ( c2.uname='sky')
) tb group by typeid,sno
order by typeid,sno
;
```

Comment: Is it slow even with index on p.uname?. And what kind of indexes are you using. Could you also give us the explain for a large query?

Comment: #3.5 `exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(...)`

Comment: I think your group by in #4 is superfluous as your unions already discard duplicates. You'd need it if you were doing union all. Not that this answers you question...

Comment: vincent,thanks! but no obvious improvement after executing dbms_stats.gather_table_stats.

Comment: I think the filter predicate (where) can't do filtering before joining if it contains OR condition between join tables. is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "union all" in you from clause and then group by.